# Checking value contained in java collection List

Tags: java, list

I have a `List` of long Arrays with the name `Arraycells`:

```
List<long[]> Arraycells = new ArrayList<>() ;
Arraycells.add(new long[]{1L, 0L});
Arraycells.add(new long[]{1L, 1L});
Arraycells.add(new long[]{1L, 2L});
```

I want to see if a long array object is contained in this list or not:

```
for (long r = 0L; r < 3; r++) {
    for (long c = 0L; c < 3; c++) {
        if (Arraycells.contains(new long[]{r, c})) { // problem is with this statement
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

How can I check the Arraycells?

Comment: To clarify, you want to see if there is a `long[]` stored in your list that has all the same items as the `long[]` you are searching for?

Comment: In the nested loop I want to see if (new long[]{1L,0L}, for example) is contained in original(Arraycells) list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try another variant using `List<Long>` instead of `long[]`:

```
List<List<Long>> cells = new ArrayList<>();
cells.add(Arrays.asList(1L, 0L));
cells.add(Arrays.asList(1L, 1L));
cells.add(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L));

for (long i = 0L; i < 3; i++) {
    for (long j = 0L; j < 3; j++) {
        if (cells.contains(Arrays.asList(i, j))) {
            System.out.println("Contains: " + i + ", " + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Also note, that code from your example checks reference equality, because arrays inherit `equals` from `Object`. On the other hand, `List.equals(...)` implementation checks whether lists contain the same elements and in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

`contains` would not work here. you should use `Arrays.equals` for array comparison.

Try this:

```
for (long r = 0L ;r < 3;r++) {
    final long copyR = r;
    for (long c = 0L; c < 3; c++) {
         final long copyC = c;
         final long[] temp = new long[]{copyR, copyC};
         if (Arraycells.stream()
                       .anyMatch(e -> Arrays.equals(e, temp))){  
                    //do something 
         }
    }
}
```

We utilise the [Stream::anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method to search through the arrays and find any matching array with [Arrays::equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(long[],%20long[])).

Comment: I would avoid creating a new array within the lambda for performance reasons.

Comment: @shmosel agreed, seems sub-optimal to construct a new array each time the lambda is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Java is an object-oriented language, so you should prefer modeling the problem with a proper *class* instead of using a primitive array directly. This makes e.g. object equality comparisons easier, by encapsulating the logic in `equals()`. You cannot override `equals()` for primitive arrays.

So you could define

```
public class ArrayCell {

    private final long[] content;

    public ArrayCell(long[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object another) {
        if (another == null || another.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        return Arrays.equals(this.content, another.content);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(content);
    }         
}
```

And the client code becomes:

```
List<ArrayCell> cells = new ArrayList<>() ;
cells.add(new ArrayCell(new long[]{1L, 0L}));
cells.add(new ArrayCell(new long[]{1L, 1L}));
cells.add(new ArrayCell(new long[]{1L, 2L}));

for (long r = 0L; r < 3; r++){
    for (long c = 0L; c < 3; c++){
        if(cells.contains(new ArrayCell(new long[]{r,c}))){
            // contains calls ArrayCell.equals() internally, so this will work
         }
    }
}
```